# how can I use window function - difficult case in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, postgresql-8.0

I have a table like below:

```
group    sequence   action          
1        1          promotion_1               
1        2          promotion_1               
1        3          promotion_2               
1        4          act1                      
1        5          act1                     
1        6          act2                      
1        7          promotion_1               
1        8          act1                                  
1        9          act2                     
1       10          promotion_1               
1       11          act1                     
2        1          promotion_2                 
2        2          act1
```

I would like to create a ranking, which will show range of promotion. So I need to have the same number for promotion and every action after this promotion:

```
group    sequence   action         parameter   
1        1          promotion_1    1             
1        2          promotion_1    2              
1        3          promotion_2    3              
1        4          act1           3              
1        5          act1           3            
1        6          act2           3            
1        7          promotion_1    4            
1        8          act1           4                        
1        9          act2           4            
1       10          promotion_1    5            
1       11          act1           5           
2        1          promotion_2    1              
2        2          act1           1
```

I read about window functions and their possibilities (for example over()), but I can create only ranking with group by "action".

Answer (score 2):

```
select T.*,
       sum(case when action like 'promotion%' then 1 else 0 end)
         over(partition by "group" order by sequence rows unbounded preceding) parameter
  from Table T
```

Comment: I get error: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause. Could you help me?

Comment: Add `rows unbounded preceding` or `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` right after `order by sequence`

Comment: @alarson008 Corrected. Thank to DuduMarkovitz

Answer (score 1):

`filter` (Starting with PostgeSQL 9.4)

```
select  *
       ,count (*) filter (where action like 'promotion%') over 
        (
            partition by  "group" 
            order by      sequence
            rows          unbounded preceding    
        )

from    mytable  T
```

---

```
+-------+----------+-------------+-------+
| group | sequence |   action    | count |
+-------+----------+-------------+-------+
|     1 |        1 | promotion_1 |     1 |
|     1 |        2 | promotion_1 |     2 |
|     1 |        3 | promotion_2 |     3 |
|     1 |        4 | act1        |     3 |
|     1 |        5 | act1        |     3 |
|     1 |        6 | act2        |     3 |
|     1 |        7 | promotion_1 |     4 |
|     1 |        8 | act1        |     4 |
|     1 |        9 | act2        |     4 |
|     1 |       10 | promotion_1 |     5 |
|     1 |       11 | act1        |     5 |
|     2 |        1 | promotion_2 |     1 |
|     2 |        2 | act1        |     1 |
+-------+----------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: I've got error "ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" Position: 36". When I copy  example code with filter from internet: SELECT
    count(*) AS unfiltered,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE i < 5) AS filtered
FROM generate_series(1,10) AS s(i); - I get the same error message..

Comment: Not relevant to your version. Are you using Redshift by any chance (or you just enjoying vintage versions)?

Comment: hmm... I use Redshift (amazon redshift)

Comment: Fixed your tags.